# Process messages from rabbitmq and store it in mongo db in python

Tags: python, mongodb, rabbitmq

I am trying to process messages got from rabbitmq and store it to MongoDB using mongoengine package. But When I try to initialize instance of Document object from mongoengine process is hanging and not returning any result.
Here is my `main.py`.

```
import os
import sys

from mongoengine import connect, disconnect
from mongoengine.connection import ConnectionFailure

from rabbitmq_client import RabbitMqClient


def main():
    connection = connect(host=MONGO_HOST, alias='raw-keyword-result')  # establish mongodb connection
    print("connection->", connection)
    settings = tracking_job_settings(os.environ)
    rbmq = RabbitMqClient(settings)
    rbmq.start_consuming(result_handler)
    print("not here")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        main()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('Interrupted')
        disconnect(alias='raw-keyword-result')
        try:
            sys.exit(0)
        except SystemExit:
            os._exit(0)
    except ConnectionFailure as e:
        print("error")
        print(e)
```

I am getting messages from RabbitMQ smoothly but I am not sure the database connection still exists when callback function **result_handler** called.
**result_handler** function.

```
def result_handler(ch, method, properties, body):
    data = json.loads(body)
    # TODO before processing the job, verify its existance in the database
    job_type = data['header']['jobType']
    try:
        if job_type == 'DetailResult':
            handle_detail_result(data)
        elif job_type == 'KeywordResult':
            handle_keyword_result(data)
        print("yeyeyeye")
        ch.basic_ack(delivery_tag=method.delivery_tag)  # TODO acknowledging job here is unsecure !!!
    except:
        pass
```

From here **handle_keyword_result** function is called with RabbitMQ message.
Here is the **handle_keyword_result** function:

```
from datetime import datetime
from mongoengine.errors import ValidationError
from orm import TrackingRawKeyword

def handle_keyword_result(message):
    """
    
    """
    entries = []
    results = message['data']['results']
    ranking = 0
    print("keyword_result")

    for result in results:

        ranking += 1
        print("result->", result)
        # try:
        print("start")
        entry = TrackingRawKeyword(
        ranking=ranking,
        date=datetime.now(),
        marketplace=message['header']['marketplace'],
        keyword=message['data']['keyword'],
        marketplaceId=result['marketId']
        )
        print("end")
        print("entry->", entry)
        entries.append(entry)
    
        # except ValidationError as ve:
        #     print("error happened")
        #     print(ve)
        #     pass  # TODO handle validation error for data entry.
    print("entries->", entries)
    TrackingRawKeyword.objects.insert(entries)
```

Here is Document object TrackingRawKeyword

```
class TrackingRawKeyword(Document):
    marketplaceId = StringField(required=True)
    market = StringField(choices=marketplaces, max_length=20, required=True)
    keyword = StringField(max_length=1024, required=True)
    ranking = IntField(required=True)
    date = DateTimeField()
```

When I run **main.py** file my program connects to RabbitMQ and also MongoDb, it receives messages from RabbitMQ and calls handlers. But in **keyword_result_handler** function, only process goes until `print("start")`. It does not continue after it. It hangs there.

Comment: It looks like you have a mismatch in the init of your TrackingRawKeyword and what is actually defined in your document model (marketplace =/= market). I suggest you to check in depth what you have in your datas and how you init your TrackingRawKeyword. Also, you should use try/except to catch errors and see what's going on in your code.

Comment: Thank you so much. I missed that point, have struggled almost 3 hours